# PHP multidimensional array handling - looking up a value 2 arrays deep

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a bit of trouble accessing data within an array that looks like the following:

```
array ( 
    0 => array ( 'value' => '46', 'label' => 'Brand A', ), 
    1 => array ( 'value' => '45', 'label' => 'Brand B', ), 
    2 => array ( 'value' => '570', 'label' => 'Brand C', ), 
);
```

Essentially I want to be able to return the contents of the label when given the value (e.g. *45 returns Brand B*), but am not sure how to do this within these levels.

Do I need to break this array down into smaller chunks through a loop of some sort to access this data?

Thanks

Comment: Whathaveyoutried.com? I'll give you a hint. Foreach loop, google multidimensional array search, in_array, array_search etc.

Comment: Your real problem is that you aren't using those labels as keys instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = array ( 
    0 => array ( 'value' => '46', 'label' => 'Brand A', ), 
    1 => array ( 'value' => '45', 'label' => 'Brand B', ), 
    2 => array ( 'value' => '570', 'label' => 'Brand C', ), 
);

$val = 45; // search for 45

foreach($arr as $vals){
   if($vals['value'] == $val){
      echo "value=".$vals['value'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "label=".$vals['label'];
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the array you need to use the value as the key:

```
array(
    '46' => 'Brand A',
    '45' => 'Brand B',
);
```

OR

```
$arrayVar['46'] = 'Brand A';
```

etc.

If you aren't the one creating the array, then you can `foreach` loop through it and rework it into a different structure.

Comment: I would've gone with using the label as the key instead of the value, but the point is made - the original array doesn't need to be multidimensional.

Comment: I agree, however it's being output that way from the API call. I probably should have asked how it was best to restructure the array to remove the unnecessary dimension - thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$arr = array ( 
    0 => array ( 'value' => '46', 'label' => 'Brand A', ), 
    1 => array ( 'value' => '45', 'label' => 'Brand B', ), 
    2 => array ( 'value' => '570', 'label' => 'Brand C', ), 
);

foreach($arr as $ele){
echo "value=".$ele['value']." and label=".$ele['label'];
}
?>
```